# Cron Triggers But Doesn't Run Script

Tags: cron, rsync

I'm having trouble scheduling a backup task. The script runs fine if done via command line, and the cron log shows that it's tried to run it, but the log file doesn't have anything in it and it doesn't seem to have actually triggered the script.

I've made sure the locations are absolute but this doesn't seem to have resolved the issue

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date)": Beginning Backup" >> /home/backups/daily.log
rsync -ahL --progress --stats --delete web3:/home/user/backups/mysql/*-$(date +"%Y%m%d")-* /home/backups/daily/web3/mysql >> /home/backups/daily.log
echo $(date)": Backup completed" >> /home/backups/daily.log
```

Cron task:

```
23 9 * * * /home/backups/web3_daily.sh
35 4 * * 0 /home/backups/web3_monthly.sh
```

Log file line:

```
Jan 30 09:23:01 localhost CROND[18044]: (backups) CMD (/home/backups/web3_daily.sh)
```